# Python setup.py: use different `install_requires` for py3?

Tags: python, pyqt, setuptools

I'm building a package that requires [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt). Pyqt5 can be pip installed on recent versions of Python 3 but not on Python 2. How can I write a setup.py that will tell py2 users to go manually get pyqt, but just automatically select and install pyqt for py3 users?

Answer (score 2):

```
setup(
...
install_requires=[
"PyQt5; python_version >= '3.0'",
"python-qt5; python_version < '3.0'",
]
)
```

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know there was a py27 package. [Later] unfortunately it seems to be Windows only (`No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-YUB1I3/python-qt5/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
` on Linux). +1 for the simple py3 only section that py2 just quietly skips